# How to restart Flask process by refreshing page

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple `Flask` application that queries a database using a set of parameters and then plots the result. This works fine, but how do I restart process(querying database, plotting data) whenever its still running and I do a refresh of the page or I click the submit button again?

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
   form = InputForm(request.form)
   if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
       data = queryDatabase(form.startdate.data, form.enddate.data)
       result = plotData(data)
   else:
       result = None
   return render_template('view.html', form=form, result=result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

view.html

```
<form method=post action="">
<table>
  {% for field in form %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ field.label }}</td>
        <td>{{ field }}</td>

    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
<p><input type=submit value=Submit></form></p>

<p>
{% if result != None %}
<img src="{{ result }}" width="500">
{% endif %}
</p>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want it to restart when you change the code? That is supported by Flask already, see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.debug. Why would you want the server to restart every time you made a request?

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, description is misleading. I made corrections.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to tell Flask to just dump processing the previous request and start a new one when it arrives - this is a... somewhat uncommon use case for a web server. Could you explain the actual problem you're trying to solve? What has changed between requests?

Comment: The data is huge and thus takes a while before I get a response. Sometimes, there's a mistake with the parameter i.e. wrong date and I want to just stop the request and put the correct one. Or is possible to have a stop button to do this?

Comment: You can add a check on the data before updating your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use queues For example Celery + Redis or Celery + RabbitMq as mentioned by others. You can examples here: http://eon01.com/blog/celery-worker-rabbitmq-broker-step-by-step-introduction/