# How to make Celery worker return results from task

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have a flask app which calls a task. The task pulls data from database, plots line charts and returns html contents which is rendered on an html page. Without Celery the Flask app works fine and renders line chart on client side, but now I want to delegated celery to run task via `RabbitMQ` broker, which it runs as I can see the log outputs in Celery shell, but the resulting html contents never gets sent back to flask server app. How to do that?

This is a follow up to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839551/how-to-restart-flask-process-by-refreshing-page/38146003#38146003.

```
#server-celery.py

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def index():
   return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def plotdata():
   form = InputForm(request.form)
   if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
       lineChart = task.main.delay(form.startdate.data, form.enddate.data) 
       return render_template('view.html', form=form, result= lineChart)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

And the task running as `Celery` worker:

```
#task.py
from celery import Celery

broker = 'amqp://localhost:5672'
app = Celery(__name__, broker=broker)

def queryDatabase(param1, param2):
   #query database, return results
   return data

def plotLineChart(data):
   #plot data as line Chart
   return LineChartHtmlcontent

@app.task
def main(param1,param2):
    data = queryDatabase(param1,param2)
    return plotLineChart(data)
```

and client html page:

```
<!--view.html-->

<form method=post action="">
<table>
  {% for field in form %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ field.label }}</td>
        <td>{{ field }}</td>

    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
<p><input type=submit value=Submit></form></p>

<p>
{% if result != None %}
<img src="{{ result }}" width="500">
{% endif %}
</p>
```

Answer (score 13):

A better solution is simply to let the task run asynchronously using celery like it was intended to be used and use javascript on the page to poll the celery task periodically to see the status.

First, when you create your celery task use the bind=True parameter. This allows you to pass `self` into the function.

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def main(self, param1, param2):
    self.update_state(state='PENDING')
    data = queryDatabase(param1,param2)
    self.update_state(state='COMPLETE')
    return plotLineChart(data)
```

You can see that we can now update the state of the task. You can modify the code to allow metadata into the `update_state` method as well, for example: `self.update_state(state='PROGRESS',  meta={'current': 0, 'total': 12})`

Now you need to poll the celery task to see how it's doing.

```
@blueprint.route('/status/<task_id>', methods=['GET'])
def taskstatus(task_id=None):
    task = main.AsyncResult(task_id)
    response = {
        'state': task.state,
    }
    return jsonify(response)
```

This will return a json object when you poll the URL with the task id. You can get the task id by using `lineChart.id` after you call `.delay()`

Please see the excellent tutorial by miguel grinberg: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask