# how to run an external python script as celery task by taking script name using flask server

Tags: python, flask, celery-task

I am using celery-flask for queuing and monitoring the task, I have four to five scripts and I want these scripts to run as a celery task by passing the script through flask server and then monitoring their status.
Here is the code I have written so far:

```
 @app.route('/script_path/<script_name>') # flask server
 def taking_script_name(script_name):
     calling_script.delay(script_name)
     return 'i have sent an async script request'



 @celery.task
 def calling_script(script_name):
   result = script_name
   return {'result':result}
```

i want the status of the script passed in the result returned in the celery task.

if anybody having another suggestion how to run external task as celery task.
thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't immediately return the result from a celery task because it is an async task. refer this answer I feel its similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/a/38270163/6798902

Comment: thanks for the response, it is fine but my real question is how to run an external script as a celery task and return its status as you suggested.

Comment: Did you find any answers to this